# Is there a cleaner way of writing functions with method call syntax?

Tags: rust

I recently found myself doing something like this to get method call syntax:

```
pub trait Test {
    fn mk_pair(self) -> (Self, Self)
    where
        Self: Sized + Clone,
    {
        (self.clone(), self)
    }
}

impl<T> Test for T {}

pub fn testy<T>(x: T) -> (T, T)
where
    T: Clone,
{
    x.mk_pair()
}
```

Silly example but as you can see I can now call `x.mk_pair()` instead of `mk_pair(x)`. Probably doesn't matter much in this case but some find method call syntax nice in some cases.

Question is, is this the minimum boilerplate required? The global impl seems a bit hacky. Is there a nicer way to give a function method call syntax without as much trait/impl tomfoolery?

Comment: So you want to be able to do `x.my_method()` for `x` of any type for which `my_method` could possibly be instantiated?

Comment: Seems like very little boilerplate to me for that functionality. Plus, then you have a trait which you could use like `fn<T: Test> function_that_makes_pairs_lots(t: T) ...`